# LuaLaTeX minimal class

Tags: luatex, packages

I'm experiencing issues with a package (actually `algorithm2e`), so I'm looking for a minimal class for testing (as [minimal](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minimal) package) with LuaLaTeX, in order to propose minimal working examples of my issues.

Is there anything like that?

Comment: minimal.cls is normally too minimal, use article.

Comment: why can you not simply use `article` class?

Comment: Thx Ulrike and David. I used to test in LaTeX with minimal. I thought there was an similar package with LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in `minimal` class that is specific to any TeX engine, it works (or not) equally for latex or pdflatex or lualatex.

Note however `minimal` does not set up fonts in any real way (it literally was written to be the minimal code that did not give an error on loading, not designed to do anything useful). As such it is a bad choice for minimal examples (with pdftex or luatex) as you can often get spurious behaviours that are artifacts of the incomplete setup rather than a result of the code being tested. It is better to use `article` class in most cases which is similarly suitable for any TeX engine.